# Stopping a Long-Running Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I create a subprocess using subprocess.Popen() that runs for a long time.  It is called from its own thread, and the thread is blocked until the subprocess completes/returns.

I want to be able to interrupt the subprocess so the process terminates when I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: This thread is a little older, but might be of help if you use Python <= 2.5 : http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t339124-subprocesspopen.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Popen.terminate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) or `.kill` function. They were added in python 2.6.